# Button setTitle is not working/ is not visible

Tags: objective-c, button

I have a simple problem with my buttons. Title is not visible. My code is :

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ikonki%d.png",i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"Normal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setEnabled:YES];

    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonHandler:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    button.tag = i;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10. + 77. * i, 125., 68 , 68);


    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: try to make button type "Roundrect" rather than custom

 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundRect];

Comment: Although you already set the image on button so why u r trying to set Title of the button?

Comment: You need to use [button setBackgroundImage: forState]; instead as your setImage: call is conflicting with setTitle:

Comment: I want to put this title down to this image...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yep, it is normal behaviour when you are using the `image` property.

**use the** `backgroundImage` **property instead of the** `image` **one, like this:**

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ikonki%d.png",i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**UPDATE #1:**

to reposition the title of the button under the button, use this way:

```
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, -60.f, 0.f)]; // align the values for your specific button
[button setClipsToBounds:false];
```

**UPDATE #2:**

to change the font of the title, try this one:

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:34.f]]; // set the font size what you desire
```

Comment: Ok now works, but the title is on the image. I'd like to move it down by my image.

Comment: Definitely Title will show over image.. in this case....Could you please post ur image

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the title then? I think I don't exactly understand your wish.

Comment: I add button with image. And I want to have title label under this button.

Comment: you can reposition the title using the `-setTitleEdgeInsets:` method, but I'm really not sure what you'd like to do exactly.

Comment: Should I use it instead od set title?

Comment: I want to have desktop with button similar to iPhone menu. That's it.

Comment: in that case, to move the title under the button use a `-setTitleEdgeInsets:` method and set the `bottom` value to minus something. for ex.: if your button's height 30, set the `bottom` value -40. your idea from now.

Comment: the `-setTitle:forState:` method **is not** instead of the `-setTitleEdgeInsets:` method.

Comment: please, read more documentation of the class references in the future and for now, check my updated answer above. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm doing a dynamic menu context and I stopped on this title. Now everything works .

Comment: Can I change the size of the font in this set title?

Comment: you can do it but not with the `-setTitle:forState:` method. please, check my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, now looks perfect. Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you forget to use the `@synthesize` on the button or variables related to it.