# UIButton title after hidden = NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've a UIButton which I built in Storyboard. Its title is "Hallo" (Entered in Attributes Inspector)
It is connected via an Outlet.
In viewDidLoad I did the following:

```
self.myButton.hidden = YES;
```

In another method I want to change the title and make the button visible:

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.myButton.hidden = NO;
```

Now the strange thing:
For a few milliseconds I see the old title "Hallo" and then it changes to "Test".
How could this be? I could understand this behaviour if I make it first visible and then change the text.

Comment: can you set titlecolor of the button? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520670/button-settitle-is-not-working-is-not-visible

Comment: Yes, but it has the same effect. At first I see my old title with the old color and then my new text with a new color.

Comment: It's odd that you would see the old value at all. Are you performing this update on the main thread?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: I didn't have the time to further investigate this, but my guess would be it has to do sth. with main thread, as Paul.s said.

Comment: The issue persists. In iOS 11.4, using the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue for the button which I put on uitableview cell. Following code was working for me. It's setting the title for all the status of the button.

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
self.myButton.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your title for highlighted state of your button too

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.myButton.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second part is called during the touch up of this button. A solution :

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
self.myButton.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only way I could get round it was to change the label to an empty string and disabling the button instead of hiding the button:

```
self.myButton.setTitle(@"", UIControlState.Normal);
self.myButton.enabled = NO;
```

Then setting the button text again and enabling it where you're showing it again:

```
self.myButton.setTitle(@"Test", UIControlState.Normal);
self.myButton.enabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [How to prevent UIButton from flashing when updating the title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19371522/1589422). When the button title is changed, the text change seems to be animated. When the title is changed while the button is hidden, that animation may still be in progress, or the animation is delayed until the button is shown.

So if you want to set the title of a button while it's hidden and then show it immediately, you should wrap both actions in a block passed to `UIView.performWithoutAnimation`, and call `layoutIfNeeded` inside that block:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.button.setTitle("New Title", for: .normal)
    self.button.isHidden = false
    self.button.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please do all these stuff in viewWillAppear delegate method.